# Could precompiled header option cause this error?

Tags: c++, c, visual-c++

I've removed "use precompiled header" option from `crypto.c`.

[image]

How to resolve this error properly?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to declare tha `crypt()` function as `extern "C"` in its header file, like this:

```
#ifdef __cplusplus
extern "C" {
#endif

void crypt(unsigned int *, unsigned int, unsigned int *);

#ifdef __cplusplus
}
#endif
```

If you don't, C++ compilers will treat it as a function with C++ (as opposed to C) linkage and will apply name mangling on it.

Comment: And not to forget `ifdef __cplusplus` if he intends to include the header in both c and c++ source.

Comment: Ah, what if want to use C, not C++? I will try to switch to C from options of `tea-test.cpp` so compiler treat it as C.

Comment: @StoryTeller Yes, I'm adding that as well.

Comment: If you want to use it in C, __cplusplus will not be defined so it won't see the extern "C" declaration.

Comment: @Pablo No problem. By the way, no, Visual Studio is not good enough for C.

Comment: @H2CO3 As far as I know it only doesn't fully support C99 standard?

Comment: @Pablo The developers of the Microsoft Visual C++ toolchain don't even know what the word "standard" means. Not C99, but there's even no compliant C89 support, the wast majority of the standard library functions are missing, and you can't compile code as C anyway, only as C++, which, knowing that C++ is **not a strict superset of C,** is a serious problem for C programmers.

Comment: @H2CO3 Bummer.. so what is the best choice for C IDE commercial or non-commercial nowadays? Sorry for going off-topic.

Comment: @Pablo I'd go for MinGW or Cygwin as it provides a POSIX-like environment and GCC as the compiler. Apart from that, you can use Code::Blocks, Eclipse, Notepad++, etc.